# Azure Logic App trigger performance when more than one files arrive at once

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a 'Azure Logic App' based scheduled trigger.

1. Total 3 files are updated at a specific Blog on an adhoc basis
2. So I created a Logic App which
   2.a) check the name of all 3 files
   2.b) total count of files should be 3
   2.c) They should have a different timestamp then the previous version
3. once all these conditions are true it triggers the specific 'Azure ML' pipeline.

But the problem is that these 3 files are pasted at once, as soon as one file is pasted pipeline triggers and in this way it triggers 3 pipelines separately.

May I request if we have any such solution where the 'Azure Logic App' run only once after the successful update of all 3 files.

Please suggest,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to get all the updated files count in a blog or container. I have created logic app that will check all the updated files count in a container based on last modified date and if the count is equal to 3 then only it will execute the next steps.

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Using List blobs action listing all the blobs in a container or folder.
- Initialized variable to get the updated files count.
- Next taken for each loop to get file properties using Get meta data action.
  [image]
- Added condition to check last modified date as shown below,
  [image]

This will check whether any updates done on files current date.

- If condition satisfies, it will increase the initialized variable to 1.
  [image]
- Next taken another action to check the updated files count as 3.
  [image]
- If it satisfies the count then added send mail actions in true block. In your case you can add Azure ML pipeline.
- Logic app run successfully and sent mail,
  [image]
- If you don't want to run all three pipelines at a time you can add setting in logic app to run only one instance of logic app by enabling concurrency control and set limit as 1.